# Quickblox Group Video Calls with Javascript SDK

Tags: javascript, webrtc, quickblox

The documentation for group video calls is missing on Quickblox website :

Group video / voice calls
- Is coming soon -
http://quickblox.com/developers/Sample-webrtc-web

I have a workaround but it's not a viable solution when there are more than 4 users.

For 3 user conference:
User 1 calls User 2 and User 3, User 2 calls User 3

And they should all hear and see each other .

Is there any other way to do it ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Javascript SDK doesn't support group video calls for now, this is for future releases

Only iOS SDK does support it  http://quickblox.com/developers/Sample-webrtc-ios

Comment: When is it going to be supported ? Any ideas?

Comment: By the end of september

Comment: Thanks for such a great product! by when can we expect js sdk for group calling?

Is there a way to use your SOAP API for developing my own group call function. if so please guide me

Comment: End of the month. We don't have SOAP API, it's REST API http://quickblox.com/developers/Overview

Comment: Any news ? I still don't see any javascript documentation for group calls .

Comment: You can check it in the separate branch https://github.com/QuickBlox/quickblox-javascript-sdk/tree/develop.webrtc